# Geolocation Rendering issue

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geolocation

I want to get the geolocation of the user everytime when he clicks it.
Here is the code

```
<script type="text/livescript">
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
      }

  function showPosition(position) {
    //  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    //  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
      var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
      var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
      latitude.value=position.coords.latitude;
      longitude.value=position.coords.longitude;
  }
  </script>
```

Calling using Button

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Check IN Details</h4>
  </div>
```

When i click on the button for the first time browser asks for the Allow location popup and renders the lat/long, and i am displaying them in the textbox. And there will be one location icon that would be generated in the URL saying this website is using the location

When i click again on the button to get the location it hangs, I mean i need to close the browser and click a button to get lat/long.

In the second instance, it is failing to get the location. There might be some refresh functions which would clear the last lat/long and get new location based on the place.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. Right now we can’t even see where you are calling those functions. (No, nothing of what you posted under “Calling using Button” seems to be actually doing that.) And then, go read up on what the purpose of `geolocation.watchPosition` is. If you want to check the position on click only, this is probably not the method you should be using in the first place. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition might be more suitable for that.

Comment: I believe you should be using getCurrentLoction instead of watchPosition because Geolocation method watchPosition() method is used to register a handler function that will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes. Now since you are calling it everytime you click the button it create another instance that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please see code below, if this is what you need, I just used getCurrentLocation menthod instead of watchPosition method because watchPosition will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes. Since you need to manually trigger a function to get the current location, you should use getCurrentLocation method, and passing a option having maximumAge: 0 to get a fresh one or will not use a cache position and will attempt to retrieve a real current position. Then passing timeout having a value of "Infinity" meaning that getCurrentPosition() won't return until the position is available. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

          <p id="demo"></p>
        </body>
    <script>

    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: Infinity, enableHighAccuracy: true};

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorHandler, options);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function errorHandler (err) {
      //TODO: Set your rules what will happen when error occured
      console.log(err);
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes. It helped a lot. Used currentPosition method which you have shared. And it works irrespective of number of times it triggered. Thanks a lot for taking a time to resolve it.

Comment: You welcome @NagendraBhat here's reference on using geolocation it would help you lot. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation

Comment: Sure. I'll take a look into. Thanks again :)